# Connected and disconnected space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness, path-connected

$GL(2 , R) = \{ M | 2 × 2 \& \det M \neq 0\}$  be defined as subset of  $\mathbb{R}^4$

For example

Consider the matrix  GL(2, R) =

\begin{matrix}
1 & 2  \\
3 & 4  \\
\end{matrix}

then (1,2,3,4)∈ R4
Accordingly, is the GL(2, R) space a connected space? Explain your answer.

> a connected space is a topological space that cannot be represented as
> the union of two or more disjoint non-empty open subsets.
>
> If X is a connected space and $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous function,
> then f(X) is connected.

**Edit:** My idea was to construct a continuous function from GL(2,R) to R4 and show that f(GL(2,R)) is not connected but I am not reaching a contradiction please help

Comment: Much easier, you can use the $det$ function to apply your result about connectedness.

Comment: How I can define the det function? More details please

Answer (score 1):

Using your result about connectedness if you define $\text{det}:GL(2,\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ as the function that sends each matrix to its determinant, then by definition of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ you have that $\text{Im}(\text{det})=\mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace$, which is not connected. Thus, since the determinant is a continuous function (it is equivalent to a polynomial function) we can apply your result and say that $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is not connected.

Comment: How we can show that R/{0} is not connected, R/{0} is not closed but how I can show that is not bounded, and what is the aim to assume the set as a subspace of R4

Comment: $\mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace=(- \infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$